# Correct user / permissions for running php script which writes to disk?

Tags: linux, php, permissions, redhat

I've got a website at

```
/var/www/html
```

Which has a couple of files, one of which is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      1609 Feb 16  2010 send_form_email.php
```

(earlier it was 644)

I can access the file fine from the web, but with the error in apache:

> PHP Warning: 
>   file_put_contents(contacts.txt) [function.file-put-contents]:
>   failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied in
>   /var/www/html/send_form_email.php on
>   line 47, referer:
>   http://www.mysite.com/

What should I be changing? The file ownership? Contacts.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If contacts.txt exists, then the permissions on contacts.txt needs to be changed, probably to 666.  If it doesn't, then the permissions on the directory you want it to be in needs to be changed to allow the webserver to write to it.

The first way is the way you want to do it, especially if there's anything else in the directory you don't want to let web users write over.

Comment: The first didnt work -rw-rw-rw-  1 root root      3381 Oct  6 10:13 contacts.txt    No change. What should I change the fokder to?

Comment: Are you sure your script is using the correct path to the file?  Try adding an `var_dump file_exists("contacts.txt");` and see if it says true. If not, use the complete path to the file (eg `/var/www/files/contacts.txt`) In order to create a new file in a directory, the directory needs to be writable by the webserver user, but doing so would make any file in the directory deletable/replaceable by any script running.  Also, out of curiosity, do you have PHP's safe mode enabled?  I don't know what kind of errors it would cause (I don't use it) but it does mess with using files.

Comment: It returns: bool(true)  and safe-mode is off

Comment: If you're using just "contacts.txt" maybe there's another file in PHP's search path that it's trying to use, try using the full path to the file?  Check and make sure the directory is something like `rwxr-xr-x` if it's owner/group is root root.  It might work with something like `rwx-r-x--x` too.  `x` on a directory gives permission to be "in" the directory, `r` gives permission to get the file listing.  If contacts.txt is in the same dir as your php script then it must already have access, or it couldn't read the php code in the first place.  If its not, every directory up to the file needs x

Comment: There's no other contacts.txt . And the permissions for 'html' folder is as: drwxr-xr-x  9 root      root 4096 Oct 16 05:52 html

Comment: Don't know what to tell you then.  Try breaking it down to the individual `$fd=fopen("contacts.txt","w"); fputs($fd,$data); fclose($fd)` and see if it can give you a better error.

Comment: I dont know what I did actually, but it started working. It could be disabling of the selinux settings.

Comment: Just for others' reference: -rw-rw-rw-  1 root root      3493 Oct 22 10:56 contacts.txt    -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      1609 Oct 19 07:45 send_form_email.php

Comment: Yeah, it was probably selinux blocking it.  If you're running auditd, it should be logging /var/log/audit/audit.log where it tells you that the webserver was blocked from accessing that file.